# NumberFormat problem

Tags: java

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/FormatNum.html

i have number 1.23 and i want to format it to 1,23. But if i have just 1 then i do not want format it to 1,00.

With ##,##0.00 i format 1.23 to 1,23 and 1 to 1,00. How can i format 1.23 to 1,23 and 1 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern instead: `##,###.##`

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##,###.##");
System.out.println(df.format(1.00));
System.out.println(df.format(1.23));
```

prints:

```
1
1.23
```

The `0` in the pattern shows zeros as "0", while `#` shows zeros as absent.

Answer (score 2):

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);

System.out.println(format.format(1.23));
System.out.println(format.format(1.0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be you can address the issue with local, Use Frech as your local for Decimal Format. Then you'll get ',' instead of '.'

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(local);
if (f instanceof DecimalFormat) {
    ((DecimalFormat) f).setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
}
```

or as below you can do it

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###.00",symbols);
System.out.println(format.format(1.22));
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double f1 = 1;
        System.out.printf("f1: %.2f%n", f1);  // prints f1: 1.00

        double f2 = 1.23;
        System.out.printf("f2: %.2f%n", f2);  // prints f2: 1.23

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

rewritten asela's and grodriguez's answers

DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###.##", symbols);
System.out.println(format.format(1.00));
System.out.println(format.format(1.23));

output:

1

1,23

Cheers!

-Saligh

Answer (score 1):

If your Locale, country settings, have decimal comma as decimal separator, then it's already handled by java, like for the swedish locale:

```
double number = 1.23;       
double otherNumber = 1.00;

System.out.println(NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("sv")).format(number));
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).format(number));

System.out.println(NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("sv")).format(otherNumber));
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).format(otherNumber));
```

which prints

1,23
1.23
1
1